# Asp .net MVC 5 Owin authentication with multiple login pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin

I have an asp.net MVC 5 site with OWIN authentication. I would like to have two different log in pages, one for regular users and one for Admin users. The login redirect path is currently set in Start.cs when setting up UseCookieAuthentication. I am pretty sure I could parse the returnUrl and look for /admin/ in the path, but that seems really hacky and prone to errors (what if there is no returnUrl?). Is there a better way? I see stuff online about using an authentication filter, but not sure if that is workable when using OWIN.

Comment: Authentication filters work fine with OWIN.

Answer (score 2):

@AntP is right, I had the same problem and I solved using Authentication Filter. (I am also using OWIN Authentication).
In my case I wanted the user to be redirected to a different Login page according to the area.

```
 public class AreaAuthorizationAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
    {
      string clientRole = "Client"; // can be taken from resource file or config file
      string adminRole = "Admin"; // can be taken from resource file or config file

      string currentArea = "";

      public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext context)
      {
        var area = context.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];

        if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(clientRole) && !(area.ToString().Equals("Client")))
            {
                context.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                currentArea = "Client";

            }
            if (context.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(adminRole) && !(area.ToString().Equals("Admin")))
            {
                context.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                currentArea = "Admin";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (area.ToString().Equals("Client"))
            {
                context.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                currentArea = "Client";
            } else if (area.ToString().Equals("Admin"))
            {
                context.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                currentArea = "Admin";
            }

        }
    }

    public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext context)
    {

           if (context.Result == null)
           {
               Debug.WriteLine("Context null");
            context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(
         new { area = "Client", controller = "Client", action = "Login", returnUrl = context.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl }));
        }
           if (context.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
           {
               if ((currentArea.Equals("Client")))
               {
                context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(
         new { area = "Client", controller = "Client", action = "Login", returnUrl = context.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl }));
            }
            else if(currentArea.Equals("Admin"))
               {
                context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(
        new { area = "Admin", controller = "Admin", action = "Login", returnUrl = context.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl }));
            }

           }


    }
}
```

Then I used my custom attribute as followes:

```
[AreaAuthorization]
public class AdminController : Controller //controller in Admin area
{
.... //actions
}


[AreaAuthorization]
public class ClientController : Controller //controller in Client area
{
.... //actions
}
```

This is my source (for custom authorize attributes): http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2935/creating-custom-authentication-filter-in-aspnet-mvc

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Have an old setup with a custom SessionAuthenticationModule that redirected according to Area that I need to replace

Answer (score 1):

You could put a constraint in your routing rules. This constraint will check is the user is of type Admin and allow (or reject) the routing.

You need to set a `IRouteConstraint` class. For example:

```
public class IsAdmin : IRouteConstraint
{
    public IsAdmin()
    {
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        bool isAdmin = false;
        // TO DO, detect if current user is Admin and return the value
        // ...
        return isAdmin; 
    }
}
```

Then in your routing rules you add that as a constraint

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { controller = new Common.Constraints.IsAdmin() }
);
```

It is a rather simple approach. I have used to prevent non admin users from accessing anything on the `/admin` section of my website and it works like a charm.